# How to convert text from Urdu to English in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-translate, transliteration

I want to convert the given user text from Urdu to English. 
When I give the source language as English and the destination language as Urdu, it seems to be working fine. But whenever I select the source language as Urdu and the destination as English, It doesn't seem to be working. I've been looking for the past 2 weeks to solve this problem but I haven't been successful as there are no resources out there which will help me with the language conversion. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance. PS: I have already included the Google Translate API to my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    // Load the Google Transliterate API
    google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });

    function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.URDU],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+e',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);


    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "It doesn't seem to be working" doesn't give us any clue as to what's wrong... and this looks like a problem which doesn't have anything to do with C# or ASP.NET as you're making the call to Google Translate straight from Javascript.

Comment: The text is being converted from English to Urdu but when I give the source language as Urdu, the text doesn't get converted to English. The same is with Hindi, Bengali and Persian.

Comment: And are any errors shown on the console? Can you get the same requests to work on the Google Translate web site? All this information should be in the question - and again, I'd suggest removing the C# and ASP.NET tags as there doesn't seem to be anything ASP.NET-specific here. (You should be able to demonstrate the same problem just in an HTML file. Such an HTML file would be a useful short-but-complete example...)

Comment: You are trying to translate text or transliterate it? They are two different things

Comment: Translation means "Translation meaning of text from one language to another", Transliteration means "Change text values from one language to equal letters in another". Translation: Hi (english) - Salom (uzbek). Transliteration: 한국어 (korean) - Hangugo (english)

Comment: I'm trying to transliterate it to another language. I can't seem to find any resources regarding transliterating the language from Urdu to English. If you do a quick search on the problem on the web, you will find the same code which I have posted in the question.

Comment: And my apologies Jon. I was working on an ASP.NET app and I though to add its tag to the question. I'm a newbie.

Comment: if you want to work with c# , so you can use world lingo translation api to translate it to one language to another language, but according to your code it's doesn't relate to c# anywhere

Comment: Quoted from official API doc for Transliterate API "Currently, English is the only supported source language". You cannot select any source language other than English as per Google's documentation.
https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from official API doc for Transliterate API "Currently, English is the only supported source language". You cannot select any source language other than English as per Google's documentation. https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started